# Comunication between azure function and aks cluster using GRPC

Tags: azure-functions, hyperledger-fabric, grpc, azure-aks

I'm having trouble comunicating an azure function with kubernetes using GRPC, I have a hyperledger fabric client running from the function connecting to the blockchain deployed in AKS.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
[Query]: evaluate: Query ID "[object Object]" of peer "peer1.xxxxxx.eastus.aksapp.io:443" failed: message=14 UNAVAILABLE: failed to connect to all addresses, stack=Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: failed to connect to all addresses
at Object.exports.createStatusError (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/grpc/src/common.js:91:15)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1209:28)
at InterceptingListener._callNext (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:568:42)
at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:618:8)
at callback (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:847:24), code=14, , flags=0, details=failed to connect to all addresses
```

The azure function is running in a node js 10-LTS environment using a service plan, its running inside a private vnet with a firewall, and communication between the azure function and the AKS has been enabled.

The weird things are:

- Running the azure function with `npm start` from my local computer using a VPN works and I can execute the chaincode as usual.
- Running the azure function from a consumtion plan to an AKS in a less secure system works and I can execute the chaincode as usual.
- Calling endpoints using https from the secure azure function to the AKS also works, I call the CA, that doesn't use GRPC from the azure function without trouble.
- Using SSH from the azure function I can run telnet peer1.xxxxxx.eastus.aksapp.io 443 successfully.

I'm a little lost with this problem it doesn't seem to be firewall, people there don't see anything blocked but I haven't been able to make it work.

Any ideas what I'm missing? what else can I try?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Here's an snippet of my tsdump:

```
tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
15:03:10.148836 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 38696, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    peer1-769d849b7f-5x782.7052 > 10.250.35.4.60612: Flags [.], cksum 0x5c26 (incorrect -> 0x8949), ack 1783377787, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 608661542 ecr 2929700376], length 0
15:03:10.148923 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 63, id 59430, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    10.250.35.4.60612 > peer1-769d849b7f-5x782.7052: Flags [.], cksum 0x5c26 (incorrect -> 0x7511), ack 1, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 2929715480 ecr 608586078], length 0
15:03:10.149285 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Reply 10.250.35.35 is-at 12:34:56:78:9a:bc (oui Unknown), length 28
15:03:10.149535 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 50400, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 70)
    peer1-769d849b7f-5x782.40006 > kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local.53: 46740+ PTR? 4.35.250.10.in-addr.arpa. (42)
15:03:10.161544 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 61799, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 175)
    kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local.53 > peer1-769d849b7f-5x782.40006: 46740 NXDomain* 0/1/0 (147)
15:03:10.161990 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 50402, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 71)
    peer1-769d849b7f-5x782.36622 > kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local.53: 53155+ PTR? 35.35.250.10.in-addr.arpa. (43)
15:03:10.162032 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 10-250-35-47.kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local tell 10.250.35.4, length 28
15:03:10.162348 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Reply 10-250-35-47.kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local is-at 12:34:56:78:9a:bc (oui Unknown), length 28
15:03:10.249331 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 63, id 53694, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 176)
    kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local.53 > peer1-769d849b7f-5x782.36622: 53155 NXDomain* 0/1/0 (148)
15:03:10.249594 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 50418, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 71)
    peer1-769d849b7f-5x782.45127 > kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local.53: 49955+ PTR? 10.45.250.10.in-addr.arpa. (43)
15:03:10.254082 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 63, id 53695, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 148)
    kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local.53 > peer1-769d849b7f-5x782.45127: 49955*- 1/0/0 10.45.250.10.in-addr.arpa. PTR kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local. (120)
15:03:10.254322 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 50419, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 71)
    peer1-769d849b7f-5x782.45289 > kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local.53: 13200+ PTR? 47.35.250.10.in-addr.arpa. (43)
15:03:10.254932 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 61808, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 161)
...
422 packets captured
422 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

Comment: can you perhaps capture the network traffic via `tcpdump` (on the host of the peer) and post it here? It might be a TLS issue, where your application isn't configured with the right TLS CA certificates.

Comment: Hi @yacovm I added a snippet of my dump, we can see that it gets lost on the return of the answer

Comment: Looks like it's trying to do a reverse DNS lookup. Can you perhaps use IP address instead of hotname on your application, and try if it works?

Comment: It works!! Thanks!!!

Comment: @yacovm Hi, it worked for a little while but then it stoped working and it started to generate hand shake errors, any clues? Tks

Comment: what errors? can you be more specific?

Comment: I think we identified the problem but we are still solving it. We are seeing that the problem is the reverse DNS service inside AKS in the last return. The call gets lost and sends the package to the nginxController. We are changing the DNS settings inside AKS to make it work. Thank you @yacovm